# Touchpad unresponsive until X restart

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, touchpad

I'm on a Netbook with Mint 13 (Ubuntu-based).
It has a touchpad which gets stuck every now and then (it's quite rare actually, but it does happen -- a few times a day).
Restarting X fixes the touchpad.
I was wondering if I can fix the touchpad without actually restarting X.

The sysinfo widget shows the name of the touchpad to be:

```
Name: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad
Bus: 0x11
Vendor: Hewlett Packard
Connected to: isa0060/serio2/input0
```

Answer (score 0):

When the mouse disappears it can sometimes be resolved by doing Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Otherwise you can find some good settings in `xset` and `xinput` and try to reset them when this happens.

These are just ideas, i don't know if it will work.

Comment: hack works for me... what is the cause? how to fix permanently?

Comment: I actually don't remember any longer what those commands did. I think the first one quits X and opens an underlying GUI-independent terminal. the second just restarts X and the GUI. So whatever process that forgot about the mouse now is restarted. Don't know remember if I found a permanent fix.